# Simplify Rational Expression Exercise

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In my Math exercise book there is the following example for reformulating a rational expression:

$\frac{1-x+x^2}{x+1} = \frac{1+2x+x^2}{x+1} - \frac{3x}{x+1} = x+1 - \frac{3x}{x+1} = x - 2 + \frac{3}{x+1}$

My problem is that i dont understand the last eqality. How does one get from $x + 1 - \frac{3x}{x+1}$ to $x-2\frac{3}{x+1}$.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac {3x} {x+1}=\frac {3(x+1)-3} {x+1}=\frac {3(x+1)} {x+1}-\frac 3 {x+1}=3-\frac 3 {x+1}$.

Hence $x+1-\frac {3x}{x+1}=x+1-3+\frac {3} {x+1}=x-2 +\frac {3} {x+1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was extremely helpful. Spot on.

Comment: Dont have enough points to upvote your answer, but i did. It should be stored internally.